# instanceof checkcast secondary_super_cache jvm bug

Tags: jvm, instanceof

There's been some posts and talks recently about this issue https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8180450.
Posts https://netflixtechblog.com/seeing-through-hardware-counters-a-journey-to-threefold-performance-increase-2721924a2822
And folks(https://twitter.com/forked_franz) who are working with it even provided some tests to reproduce it https://github.com/RedHatPerf/type-pollution-agent
i.e. test case
https://github.com/franz1981/java-puzzles/blob/d1652dae963a970c87b9222d54d8b47e46f45ee9/src/main/java/red/hat/puzzles/polymorphism/CheckcastContentionTest.java

Can someone explain in more details what's really going on in this test?
As we iterate through a collection of homogeneous objects and access each one there's no type_pollution penalty and otherwise there is one. Why so?

one more test example
https://gist.github.com/tjake/1b42331a11903980efeb4d3d7dd1df1b

Comment: You've already mentioned many links that have SO MUCH information about the issue, that it's hard to add something fundamentally new without just repeating what's already there. Try to be more specific in the question.

Comment: @apangin, I want to make sure that I understand it correctly. If i.e. we have a class that implements multiple interfaces and a code pattern like this: if (class instanceof I1){} then later if(class instanceof I2){} so we encounter the mentonied issue. But in that test case  we do not use instanceof, rather we use generic collections and compiler add checkcast byte code, which is someting similiar to instanceof? I'm not that familiar with jmh test ramework, so does one test execution thread execute both benchmark methods in order and that way produces the issue?

Comment: Yes, `checkcast` updates secondary super cache the same way as `instanceof`. JMH runs each benchmark in a separate JVM.